# Fail to connect to camera service on Flash Light Blinking

Tags: java, android, telephonymanager

I am develop an Android App that flash on incoming call and on sms but the problem is that for the first time flash start blinking on incoming call or on sms but for the second time it throw an Exception that "Fail to connect to camera service"

**Here is my Source Code**

```
public class CallReceiver extends PhonecallReceiver {

    private static Camera camera =null;
    private boolean isFlashOn;
    Camera.Parameters params;
    private boolean isBlinking = false;
    String myString = "010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101";

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {

        isBlinking = true;
        setFlashBlinking(ctx);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
        Log.d("arsalan", "Out going call started");
        turnOffFlash();
      /*  myString = "1";
        onIncomingCallStarted(ctx, number, start);*/
    }

    @Override
    protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end) {
        Log.d("arsalan", "incoming call is ended");
        myString = "1";
        turnOffFlash();
        //onIncomingCallStarted(ctx, number, start);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end) {
        Log.d("arsalan", "on out going call is ended");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
        Log.d("arsalan", "On Missed call");
        turnOffFlash();

        // onIncomingCallStarted(ctx, number, start);
    }
    private void turnOnFlash() {
        if (!isFlashOn) {
            camera = Camera.open();
            params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            camera.setParameters(params);
            camera.startPreview();
            isFlashOn = true;
        }
    }

    private void turnOffFlash() {

        if (isFlashOn) {
           // params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            camera.setParameters(params);
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
            isFlashOn = false;
        }
    }

    public void setFlashBlinking(Context context) {

        MyPreference preference = MyPreference.getInstance(context);
        //checking that flash light is available or not
        if (FlashLight.hasFlashLight(context)) {

            long blinkDelay = preference.getCallBlinkingDelay();

            for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {

                if (isBlinking == false) {
                    break;
                }
                if (myString.charAt(i) == '0') {
                    turnOnFlash();

                } else {
                    turnOffFlash();
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(blinkDelay);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void setFlashBlinking(boolean blinking) {
        isBlinking = blinking;
    }
}
```

PhonecallReceiver is an abstract class the extends Broadcast Receiver for detection of incoming call

**setFlashBlinking()** method is used to turn on/off flash light and **setFlashBlinking(boolean isBlinking)**  method(for stopping flash blinking) is used to stop the loop when the call is received or missed call.

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.creativelabs.flashoncallandsms">
]
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

    <permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
        android:protectionLevel="normal"
      />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".BroadCastReceiver.CallReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".BroadCastReceiver.SmsListener">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

How to resolve this problem "Fail to connect to camera services"

 Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: Check whether the camera resources are released properly. Have sufficient logs and check.

Comment: what is minSdkVersion ? if you are using 21, then make a use of android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager

Comment: my  minSdkVersion is 15

Comment: were you getting any issues with cameraManager ? I think **cameraManager.setTorchMode** is simple to use and it works fine.

Comment: but what about below 21 version

Comment: I think you should move your code in service or create a BG thread and run there.